# IIF Statement in TablixFilter issue

Tags: filter, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, iif-function

I'm trying to filter a matrix in my report. I have names of 4 drivers and I want the Matrix5 to show the name of a default driver in case SELECT ALL is checked in filter. Otherwise I want the matrix to show whoever is checked.

I set an expression at matrix filter as;

```
=IIF(Parameters!Sofor.Count=4,"abcdef",Parameters!Sofor.Value)
```

-abcdef is the name of the default driver for the tablix
-Sofor is the driver name parameter and has 4 total possible name options, 5 if we consider SELECT ALL too.

It works well if I check SELECT ALL but stops working if I select only one option.

Error I'm getting is as follow;

"The processing of FilterExpression for the tablix "Tablix5" cannot be performed. Cannot compare data of types System.String and System.Object[]. Please check the data type returned by the FilterExpression"

Though the error sounds pretty self explanatory I still can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any help please?

Comment: Is that your **Expression** or the **Value** in the Filter? It sounds like you have your formula in the Expression and the field to filter by in the Value when it should be the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters!Sofor.Value is an array of values (the object) because its a multi-select parameter.  (what happens when the user chooses 2 drivers?)

Try

```
=IIF(Parameters!Sofor.Count=4,"abcdef",Parameters!Sofor.Value(0))
```